# RavenDB Index creation with "SubQuery"

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I am currently not able to create an index with somekind of a subquery.
Let me show you what I am talking about

```
from book in orderbooks
where
  book.LastTradeTime == orderbooks.Select(x => x.LastTradeTime).Max() 
select new { ... }
```

Anyone has a clue how I can do such a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that with ordering:

```
var result = book.Where(t => t.LastTradeTime > 0).OrderByDescending(t => t.LastTradeTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Hm, but I can't use that directly in the creation process for the index. While creating, I need the possibility to do subqueries, like in the SQL environment. Using a query for getting results from a document store is not what I intend.